# Move SKSpriteNode In the same direction of a other

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I want to move a SKSpriteNode when i touch a Button in the same direction of a other but faster. I have this for the moment

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    Vaisseau = SKSpriteNode(texture: VaisseauTexture)
    Vaisseau.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
    Vaisseau.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Vaisseau.size)
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bonus
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Meteorites
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(Vaisseau)

    BoutonMissile = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
    BoutonMissile.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 4 - 120,self.frame.size.height / 4 + 240)
    BoutonMissile.addTarget(self, action: Selector("TireMissile"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    BoutonMissile.setBackgroundImage(ImageBoutonMissile, forState: .Normal)
                self.view?.addSubview(BoutonMissile)

        }

        func TireMissile() {
            let missile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Missile")
            missile.position = CGPointMake(Vaisseau.position.x,Vaisseau.position.y)
            self.addChild(missile)


        }
```

I want when I press the button `buttonMissile` that creat and moves in the same direction of my `Vaisseau` who i move with my finger.

EDIT :

I search how to convert a radian in vector and i found this . This is perfectly work but my `missile` always go on the right of my `Vaisseau`

```
func TireMissile() {

        let missile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Missile")
        missile.position = CGPointMake(Vaisseau.position.x,Vaisseau.position.y)
        missile.zRotation = Vaisseau.zRotation
        missile.zPosition = -1
        self.addChild(missile)
        let Dx = cos(Vaisseau.zRotation)
        let Dy = sin(Vaisseau.zRotation)
        print(cos(Vaisseau.zRotation))
        print(sin(Vaisseau.zRotation))
        missile.runAction(SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: Dx * 4000 , dy: Dy * 4000), duration: 10))

    }
```

EDIT :

I found the solution : I replace

```
let Dx = cos(Vaisseau.zRotation)
let Dy = sin(Vaisseau.zRotation)
```

to

```
let Dx = cos(Vaisseau.zRotation + CGFloat(M_PI/2))
let Dy = sin(Vaisseau.zRotation + CGFloat(M_PI/2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into `SKActions`,  what you do is alter the time it takes to reach its destination,  or the `duration` as it is called:

e.g.

```
missle.runAction = SKAction.moveByX(100, y: missle.position.y, duration:1) //will move 100 pixels in 1 second
self.runAction = SKAction.moveByX(100, y:self.position.y, duration:2) //will move 100 pixels in 2 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have try your code but this juste move missile in one direction and no in the direction of my `vaisseau` :/

Comment: yes , you need to actually figure out the numbers yourself, you can't just copy and paste this answer. if your vaisseau is moving in a -dx direction,  you need to make the move by number -

Comment: I have try something look in my EDIT please